# How to make Chrome/Chromium remember passwords in the gnome seahorse keyring?

Tags: gnome, password, chromium, keyrings, seahorse

Is it possible to make chrome or chromium (as that comes default in the repos) to use the Gnome seahorse as password vault?

I have not found a way to do this for Firefox either, but maybe a solution for Firefox will lead to a solution for Chrome.

FYI: Epiphany is properly integrated into Gnome by default, and *does* use the default password vault. It would be great to at least have all passwords in a single, actually secure, place, instead of laying around in my home-dir.

Even better would be if somehow they could re-use eachothers passwords, but that depends on the implementation of this integration, i guess.

Comment: Please note that "seahorse" is a front end application for the Gnome Keyring vault, "gnome seahorse keyring" is not correct ;)

Comment: I'd like to fix it above, but please first let me know if the following is correct: "to use the Gnome keyring vault as password vault for Chromium"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/07/chrome-dev-channel-adds-gnome-keyring-support-for-saving-passwords/ , that is available, you will need to update the chrome launcher to use –password-store=gnome.

There was a Firefox addon providing gnome keyring integration, I can no longer find it.

**EDIT:** Added link to Firefox addon code and bugzilla ticket

https://github.com/mdlavin/firefox-gnome-keyring

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=309807

Answer (score 2):

Well this doesn't answer the question but may be appreciated.
There is a nice addon called Lastpass.
It works on IE, firefox and chromium (and there are some kind of javascript bookmarks to enable its functionning on non supported browsers).

True that nothing to do with seahorse.
But autosync between firefox and chromium (your last will) and also autosync between computers (windows included).
Many secure features (generate password, receiving mails on password changes, etc).