# How to make Firefox use the Gnome Keyring vault for password storage and retrieval?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, security, password

With [Chrome it is quite simple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28019/how-to-make-chrome-chromium-remember-passwords-in-the-gnome-seahorse-keyring) to use Gnome Keyring for password storage. But with Firefox 4 on ubuntu 11.04, I don't know how to achieve this.

I remember that firefox 4 supposedly has OS integration for this, but cannot find the reference anymore.

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There was an extension in AMO site, but it seems it has been removed. You can get the source code tho, from https://github.com/mdlavin/firefox-gnome-keyring

I haven't used this for a while and I don't know about it's security, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: The mentioned addon, unfortunately only builds against FF3, not FF4.

Answer (score 1):

The working firefox 4+ extension is found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/save-firefox-passwords-in-gnome-keyring.html

It is not yet perfect, but works.

Comment: Note: this broke soon after again; the extension is not kept in pace with Firefox's fast release-pace.