# Chromium : how can I set up seahorse/gnome-keyring to ask for a "master password"

Tags: password, chromium, gnome-keyring, seahorse

I've just started using chromium today, and I'd like to have a "master password" feature as I did using Firefox.

From what i read, it's not native in chrome, but requires the use of gnome-keyring and its interface seahorse.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28019/how-to-make-chrome-chromium-remember-passwords-in-the-gnome-seahorse-keyring) explains precisely what i need to do, but i don't see how to update chrome in order to ask me a password on startup ( especially the part 'update the chrome launcher to use –password-store=gnome').

Could someone explain it to the newbie I am ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the feature is in Beta here chrome://flags/
go to that page- Look for the New Profile Management experiment- and set to enabled- and you should be able to lock and set a password from there.

I've not tried it on Chromium however.

While there maybe reasons against it you can always go to https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html and download Chrome then do the same hting if that suits your purpose.

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, but still another way to turn around my problem ; it's not implemented in chromium though. 
Thanks for the answer anyway !